# ¿Por qué cuando marco una respuesta como aceptada no se da al mismo tiempo un voto a favor?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-aceptada, votos-positivos

Cuando hago una pregunta y marco una respuesta como aceptada (correcta), aún cuando queda marcada con el check (✔) de color verde y otorga +15 puntos, no otorga automáticamente un voto a favor a dicha respuesta para así sumar +10 puntos correspondientes a este proceso para sumar un total de +25 puntos a la respuesta aceptada.

En teoría, siendo el OP de la pregunta y marcando la respuesta como aceptada, debería colocar el voto a favor automático. Sería lógico y a la vez eficaz porque a muchos de los que marcan la respuesta como aceptada se les olvida en la mayoría de los casos dar el voto a favor.

Me ha pasado que doy respuestas correctas, son marcadas como aceptadas y si aún nadie más ha dado un voto a favor sale el marcador en "0". Se ve muy extraño una respuesta aceptada con el contador de votos a favor en "0"... más que extraño, yo diría poco confiable aún cuando al OP sí le sirvió, e incluso dejó un comentario agradeciendo el apoyo.

A muchos se les olvidará cuando la marcan como correcta el también marcar la flecha arriba y por eso digo que se les olvida puntuar con voto a favor la respuesta.

¿Hay algún motivo especial por el cual esto actualmente no sucede?

**Ejemplo explicativo:** muestro una imagen con una de mis preguntas:

> [image: Pregunta de ejemplo]

En la pregunta he marcado como respuesta correcta la suministrada por el usuario @A.Cedano (gracias nuevamente por la colaboracion Sr. Cedano). Sin embargo, al marcar como correcta la pregunta, el check (✔) cambia de color gris a verde indicando que esa respuesta la elegí como aceptada:

> [image: Respuesta_ejemplo_check]

Sin embargo, también se nota que no está marcada la pregunta con voto a favor. Tuve que hacerlo manualmente como muestra la siguiente imagen:

> [image: imagen_ejemplo_check_tildado]

---

En Conclusión, y como el mismo @A.Cedano me ha ayudado a explicar mejor en uno de sus comentarios, la pregunta en concreto es: ¿por qué no se automatiza en una sola acción el marcado de respuesta aceptada y el voto a favor de esa respuesta?

Comment: Si exactamente Flxtr. Podrías por favor también aclararme que significa "OP" y disculpa

Comment: @Flxtr creo que la duda planteada es *¿por qué cuando marco una respuesta como aceptada (activando el ✔ de color verde), no se da al mismo tiempo un voto a favor a la respuesta aceptada?* Creo que Huskie ha querido decir que, *si la marco como aceptada es lógico que considere que dicha respuesta merece además un voto a favor*. En resumen: *¿por qué no se automatiza en **una sola acción** el marcado de respuesta aceptada y el voto a favor de esa respuesta?*

Comment: Exactamente @A. Cedano. Muchas gracias realmente eso es lo que intentaba decir. Actualizaré la pregunta para colocar justo lo que dices "¿por qué no se automatiza en una sola acción el marcado de respuesta aceptada y el voto a favor de esa respuesta?" Porque es exactamente mi duda

Comment: @A.Cedano Permiteme tomar como título "¿por qué cuando marco una respuesta como aceptada (activando el ✔ de color verde), no se da al mismo tiempo un voto a favor a la respuesta aceptada?" ya que es mas apropiado que el que le coloqué en un principio a mi pregunta.

Comment: Tengo que hacer memoria y buscar en meta post de hace 5 años  para contestar esto? o me creerian de una?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286594/special-upvote-privilege-when-accepting-answer a ver si esto te sirve como base.. hay problemas de privilegios, medallas y estoy seguro que habia algo mas...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269928/should-acceptance-of-an-answer-carry-an-automatic-upvote-from-the-questioner del 2014... si queres traduzco todas esas respuestas

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la aclaración, la pregunta ahora tiene mayor sentido (al menos para mí)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/686/141717 el tema viene desde el 2009.. o sea.. desde los comienzos...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la aclaratoría. Ya me quedó claro con lo que me explico el Sr. Alvaro Montoro en su respuesta. Una pregunta porque me han dado negativo? la pregunta no es mala y no existe una parecida en SOes

Comment: @Huskie Meta es diferente al sitio principal. En Meta, los votos son si uno está a favor o en contra de la propuesta. Por eso en Meta no hay reputación y puede quedar en -1000 que no te cambia nada

Comment: Con razón! gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo sería partidario de **no** hacerlo.

Algunos motivos por los que creo que no se debería dar un voto positivo automático al aceptar:

1. Votar positivo y aceptar una respuesta son funciones diferentes del sistema y cada una tiene un significado:

   - Aceptar respuesta = La respuesta es útil para la persona que pregunta
   - Votar positivo = La respuesta es buena

   Sé que puede parecer que si una respuesta es útil eso quiere decir que es buena, y tiene sentido (al menos para la persona que escribió la pregunta), pero ese no siempre es el caso. Yo tengo 60+ respuestas aceptadas sin un voto positivo y, sinceramente, creo que muchas de ellas tampoco se merecen el +1 porque, aunque sirvieron al usuario, tampoco son tan buenas.
2. No todos los usuarios tienen privilegio de voto. Para conseguirlo se necesitan sólo 15 puntos (que no son tantos) pero también se *pierde* temporalmente si se llega al límite diario. ¿Qué ocurriría si un usuario que no puede votar acepta una respuesta? ¿Se le estaría dando un voto adicional o en ese caso no se daría el +1?
3. Los votos se bloquean después de un tiempo, las aceptaciones no. Si un usuario acepta una respuesta y se le da un +1 automático pero luego decide que otra respuesta es mejor (por el motivo que sea), ¿qué se hace con ese voto: se quita o se deja? ¿Y si sí/no ha pasado el tiempo de bloqueo?
4. Permite utilizar el sistema a favor de los usuarios que no siguen las reglas. Por ejemplo, las preguntas con respuestas positivas no se eliminan; entonces si un usuario escribe una pregunta mala pero acepta una de las respuestas, al asignársele un +1 a la respuesta, se asegura la "supervivencia" de la pregunta (a no ser que un moderador actúe). Y hay usuarios que podrían explotar eso de manera intencionada.

Comment: Esta era la explicación que buscaba. Ahora me queda claro el por qué no se toma en conjunto respuesta aceptada y voto a favor. Muchas gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: De hecho, votar positivo es para cuando la "*respuesta es útil*" (no "*buena*" -sea lo que sea que cada uno interpreta por eso). Una diferencia que se suele hacer es que se acepta la respuesta que fue útil para el autor, y se votan las publicaciones que son útiles para la comunidad. Por ejemplo, yo podría llegar a aceptar una respuesta de sólo código que me fue útil para resolver mi problema, y no votarla si creo que no es útil para la comunidad... Esta respuesta es útil ;-)

Comment: @Mariano "_yo podría llegar a aceptar una respuesta de sólo código que me fue útil para resolver mi problema_"... eres un monstruo :P

Comment: Muy buenos puntos para la explicación ^^